# What does "WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'paths' = 'key1, key2, key3') " really do in Hive DDL json serde?

Tags: hive, ddl, amazon-athena

Much appreciated if anyone can provide a reference to this clause. I have been searching online with little luck.

Comment: What is "python serde"? Could you add a relevant link?

Comment: Sorry typo, *json* serde

Comment: It looks like "path" is useless. See the link here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118660/serde-properties-list-for-aws-athena-json

Comment: Hive doesn't use it. Glue seems to generate that, but I'm not sure how Glue uses it

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing. There is nothing in the code of the serde that reads the `path` property – and as far as I can tell there has never been. This is probably documentation that has been handed down generation by generation from the earliest Hive examples.

Comment: I know it is used by HiveWarehouseConnector when you try to query hive tables with SparkSQL.

Comment: The context here is Amazon Athena, where it does nothing. It's a serde property and the code for the serde in question does not contain any references to the property.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Amazon with this:

> There is some documentation that says: with serdeproperties (
> 'paths'='requestBeginTime, adId, impressionId, referrer, userAgent,
> userCookie, ip' ) This stackoverflow:
> [What does "WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'paths' = 'key1, key2, key3') " really do in Hive DDL json serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170339/what-does-with-serdeproperties-paths-key1-key2-key3-really-do-in-h)
> Seems to say that is not needed. Can you remove it or explain it?

and they replied:

> Thanks for your feedback. I confirmed that the WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
> line is not required for the example documented. We’ll get the line
> removed. Thanks once again for your help in improving the Athena
> documentation.

Comment: As of this morning, it is gone.