# SerDe properties list for AWS Athena (JSON)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, hive-serde

I'm testing the Athena product of AWS, so far is working very good. But I want to know the list of SerDe properties. I've searched far and wide and couldn't find it. I'm using this one for example `"ignore.malformed.json" = "true"`, but I'm pretty sure there are a ton of other options to tune the queries.

I couldn't find info for example, on what the "path" property does, so having the full list will be amazing.

I have looked at Apache Hive docs but couldn't find this, and neither on AWS docs/forums.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It seems you are using the Openx-JsonSerDe
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html

```
// properties used in configuration
public static final String PROP_IGNORE_MALFORMED_JSON = "ignore.malformed.json";
public static final String PROP_DOTS_IN_KEYS = "dots.in.keys";
public static final String PROP_CASE_INSENSITIVE ="case.insensitive" ;
```

https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/blob/master/json-serde/src/main/java/org/openx/data/jsonserde/JsonSerDe.java

Comment: So there are only three properties? What about the "path" property that I saw in the Amazon docs, where is that?

Comment: Show me the link

Comment: Will be this one: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html

Comment: Seems to me like a dummy properties that have no effect.

Comment: As of 9/2/18, the case insensitive property does not work as AWS does not have the version of Openx-JsonSerDe that implements this property. I can confirm that `dots.in.keys` works. Additionally, a missing feature not mentioned here is the ability to remap fields with name violations such as `foo-bar` by adding serde property `mapping.foo_bar = foo-bar` does work. The schema should then specify `foo_bar` as the column name and you should delete / re-add all partitions to pull the schema update.

Comment: I couldn't work with caseInsensitive nor remapping in Athena + Glue... I agree with @DavidדודוMarkovitz that they seem dummy properties. Nevertheless, they seem to be in the AWS documentation... anybody could move on since 2018?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [release notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2019-02-18.html) (see bullet #2 please), the JSON OpenX SerDe used in Athena has been improved. The improvements include, but are not limited to, the following:

- Support for the **ConvertDotsInJsonKeysToUnderscores** property. When set to TRUE, it allows the SerDe to replace the dots in key names with underscores. For example, if the JSON dataset contains a key with the name "a.b", you can use this property to define the column name to be "a_b" in Athena. The default is FALSE. By default, Athena does not allow dots in column names.
- Support for the **case.insensitive** property. By default, Athena requires that all keys in your JSON dataset use lowercase. Using WITH SERDE PROPERTIES ("case.insensitive"= FALSE;) allows you to use case-sensitive key names in your data. The default is TRUE. When set to TRUE, the SerDe converts all uppercase columns to lowercase.

For more information, see [OpenX JSON SerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html#openxjson) in the *Amazon Athena User Guide*.